# How to Add Git Bash to VsCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, git-bash

[It is not showing Git Bash Option in while selecting terminal in VsCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkNPK.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Make sure you have already installed [Git for Windows](https://git-scm.com/download/win)
2. In VS Code, go to Command Palette (⇧⌘P) with **Terminal: Select Default Profile** or **Terminal: Select Default Shell** in older versions, then select available shell in this case, **Git Bash**, in the dropdown list.
3. Click on + sign next to terminal list as shown below:
   [image]

At this point, the Git Bash should be successfully added.

PS. The list might disappear if the VS Code is closed. Only the default shell will show up. You have to do the steps above again.