# VSCode error in settings when trying to set Git Bash as default profile for terminal

Tags: windows, windows-10, visual-studio-code, git-bash

I tried to set Git Bash as the default terminal in VSCode, but I can't do it successfully. I've tried following the next articles:

1. [How do I use Bash on Windows from the Visual Studio Code integrated terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42606837/how-do-i-use-bash-on-windows-from-the-visual-studio-code-integrated-terminal)
2. [How to Add Git Bash to VsCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65438333/how-to-add-git-bash-to-vscode)

But they haven't resolved my issue.

I managed to generate profiles in `settings.json`, but Git Bash doesn't work for some reason unknown to me and VsCode shows an error.

My `settings.json`:

```
{
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
        "PowerShell": {
            "source": "PowerShell",
            "icon": "terminal-powershell"
        },
        "Command Prompt": {
            "path": [
                "${env:windir}\\Sysnative\\cmd.exe",
                "${env:windir}\\System32\\cmd.exe"
            ],
            "args": [],
            "icon": "terminal-cmd"
        },
        "Git Bash": {
            "source": "Git Bash",
            "path": "C:\\git-sdk-64\\git-bash.exe",
            "args": [
                "--login",
                "-i"
            ]
        },
        "Cygwin": {
            "path": "C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\bash.exe",
            "args": [
                "--login"
            ]
        }
    },
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Git Bash"
}
```

The error:

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this?

My VsCode version:

```
Version: 1.57.1 (user setup)
Commit: 507ce72a4466fbb27b715c3722558bb15afa9f48
Date: 2021-06-17T13:28:07.755Z
Electron: 12.0.7
Chrome: 89.0.4389.128
Node.js: 14.16.0
V8: 8.9.255.25-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19042
```

### Edit:

I use [git SDK](https://github.com/git-for-windows/build-extra/releases/tag/git-sdk-1.0.8), which is like git-bash but not exactly. Maybe this is the problem?

Comment: Try completely restarting VS Code after making these changes.  I've discovered in a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68068359/gitbash-not-showing-up-as-a-terminal-option-in-vscode/68068807#68068807) that I needed to do this in order for VS Code to pickup the newly added profile.

Comment: @TimothyG. VsCode restart failed to help in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just met a same problem. And the solution on my VS Code 1.60.0 is also to rename `Git Bash` into `GitBash`.

During debugging using Developer Tools, I found VS Code always "merge" object values with the default values of a same key, so:

- in VS Code, the `Git Bash` key has a default value of `{ source: "Git Bash" }`
- I once wrote `{..., "Git Bash": { "path": "D:\\Git\\usr\\bin\\bash.exe", ... }}`
- and then the merged value is `{..., "Git Bash": { "source": "Git Bash", "path": "...", ... }}`
- during a function named `showProfileQuickPick`, VS Code calls `_detectProfiles`

  - this function sends values of `terminal.integrated.profiles.windows` and `terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows` to its `_primaryOffProcessTerminalService`
  - the value of `profiles` is just the merged one
- as a result, the object of `Git Bash` is somehow "illegal" and then ignored

On the contrary, `GitBash` means to declare a new profile object, so it should work.

Comment: This works for me now. I remember it didn't work in the past. VSCode updated a few times since I made the post, tho, and now I have version 1.60.0. Also I removed 'source: "Git Bash"' from the settings.json.

Answer (score 6):

this finally worked for me

```
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
        "PowerShell": {
            "source": "PowerShell",
            "icon": "terminal-powershell"
        },
        "Command Prompt": {
            "path": [
                "${env:windir}\\Sysnative\\cmd.exe",
                "${env:windir}\\System32\\cmd.exe"
            ],
            "args": [],
            "icon": "terminal-cmd"
        },
        "GitBash": {
            "path": ["C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe"],
            "args": [],
            "icon": "terminal-bash"
        }
    },
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "GitBash"
}
```

Comment: Now it works. Maybe an update to 1.60.0 fixed this particular issue.

Comment: Supply the empty array to args fixed my issue. Thanks.