# VS Code 1.60 will not run my selected default terminal upon startup and instead runs PowerShell

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

For months I have been using Git Bash as my default terminal. Upon start up it loads 1 terminal plus any additional terminals as defined in my "terminals.json" file using the "Terminals Manager" extension. Everything has been working fine up until today, when I opened vscode up and it launched powershell instead of Git Bash for all my terminals. I have restarted vscode, and also restarted my pc but that did not help.

As mentioned above it is my default profile:

[image]

And here are my settings:

[image]

Also, I can still run Bash on VS Code and it works just fine, however it won't run on start up anymore.
What is happening?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/69048033/836330

Comment: Thanks Mark. Had to go back to previous version. Also had to add `"args": ["--login"]` because it would not recognise my _.profile_ file.

Answer (score 0):

This was probably caused by this bug [that got fixed](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/132150#issuecomment-918735296): 
[Powershell console opens every time I launch VS Code with a project
#132150](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/132150).