# Updated VS Code gives PowerShell in Terminal despite "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows" set to "Command Prompt"

Tags: visual-studio-code

As a result of an update, my `settings.json` got changed as follows. I previously explicitly specified `cmd.exe` (with path) for my default Terminal shell.

Now, something changed. There is "Command Prompt" set in the new params but **I still get PowerShell opened in the terminal by default**.

```
/*"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\cmd.exe",*/
/*"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": [],*/
"python.analysis.extraPaths": [
    "C:\\gitForVS\\sm_telework\\api"
],
"python.experiments.optOutFrom": [
    "PtvsdWheels37 - experiment"
],
"notebook.cellToolbarLocation": {
    "default": "right",
    "jupyter-notebook": "left"
},
"debug.focusWindowOnBreak": false,
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Command Prompt",
"terminal.integrated.automationShell.windows": ""
```

Comment: Some info:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/69048033/836330