# Integrating MINGW64 into Visual Studio Code

Tags: git, terminal, visual-studio-code, mingw-w64, msys2

From https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal, I have been able to put the shell inside the shell choices but when I select it, it pops up a new window separate from the VSCode's terminal. How do I solve this problem?

This is what I have done in *settings.json*:

```
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
...
"MINGW64": {
            "path": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64.exe"
        }
}
```

I also have a problem *git*. I installed *git* as a package from *msys2*. I have set up all the basic `git config` parameters.

But when I try `git config --global -e`, it give an error:

`hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file... code --wait: line 1: code: command not found error: There was a problem with the editor 'code --wait'.`

So I tried in *cmd*, and it worked. `where code` also only worked in *cmd*.

So I was wondering what would be the problem. Could it be something to do with `PATH`? Or something to do with the above question?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Would that method still work? I have checked out that post before but didn't use it because it uses `terminal.integrated.shell.windows` which is the outdated version right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I tried in cmd, and it worked. where code also only worked in cmd.

Except it is the `code.cmd` which is actually executed.
In a bash session, check if the `$PATH` references the same folder as in CMD.

Consider also using [Git For Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) directly: you can add its [`git bash` to VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65440060/6309)

In the .bashrc:

```
export PATH=$PATH:"/C/Users/User1/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin"
```

Comment: you mean the `PATH` of the `core.editor` for _git_ should be the same for _bash_ and _cmd_?

Comment: @Zernoxi Yes, but with a different formet in a bash session: `/C/...`

Comment: `[core] editor = code --wait` Both sessions reference the same _.gitconfig_ file. Is that not suppose to be the case? @VonC

Comment: @Zernoxi The `~/.gitconfig` is one thing. It won't work without the correct `$PATH` in your bash session.

Comment: Could you please explain how to set that up? @VonC

Comment: My `$PATH` in bash is also not inheriting Windows `%PATH%`.

Comment: Exactly. You need to export the path in your.bashrc

Comment: I added this `PATH=$PATH:/C/Users/User1/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin` and got `bash: VS: command not found` when I opened bash open again.

Comment: Did you add `export` before PATH=... ?

Comment: Never mind, I forgot to put quotes around `Microsoft VS Code`. But thanks for the help! Now need to figure out how to add MINGW64 shell to VSCode.

Comment: @Zernoxi Well done. I have edited the answer accordingly.