# Java code is running properly in output section but not runs in terminal section of vs code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, terminal, java.util.scanner

Actually I am a beginner in coding and I am facing an issue  and I am unable to find the solution of this issue on google.
The problem is that if I run the code in output section of vs code then it runs properly but if I turn on the "Run in terminal" then it runs but does not gives an output.

[image: This is the Screen shot of output when I run the code in output section]

[image: This is the screen shot of output when I run the code in vs code terminal]

I don't know what is the issue that it does not give output in terminal and I am running the code in terminal because we can't take the user input in the output section so we must have to run the code in terminal to take input from the user.

I am trying to run the code in vs code terminal but it is not showing the output.
it runs the code but does not give output.
I want to run the code in terminal.

Comment: what happens when you only enter the command "java -version" in that terminal?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please [edit] your question. Code and error messages should be written as text, not images. You can leave the images as a supporting info.

Comment: Why do you use a mingw64 terminal? Because that is your problem in MingW the path `E:\university work\OOP Java\practice1\src` does not exist as you can see from the line above. The Paths has to be written as `/e/university/OOP Java/practice1/src`. You better should use a common cmd.exe or powershell terminal if you want to work with Windows paths.

Comment: Maybe this will help? [Integrating MINGW64 into Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69341108/integrating-mingw64-into-visual-studio-code)

Comment: May I know what's going on with the problem? If it has been solved, can you change the status of the answer to help more people with similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

You are using **Code Runner** to run the program, which is not a best practice. You'd better use the official Java extension package to execute the program.

You can click `Run` or `Debug` on the code editing page to run or debug the program.

[image]

You can also select `Run Java` from the triangle button in the upper right corner.

[image]